# Save Rmarkdown's report tables and figures to file

Tags: r, r-markdown

Simple question:

I have an `Rmarkdown` script where I generate tables and figures:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r libraries}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
```


# Table
```{r print.table,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS,value=1:26)
knitr::kable(df) %>% kable_styling()
```


# Figure
```{r print.params.table,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=id,y=value))+geom_point()
```
````

My question is if there's a way to be able to save the tables and figures to files (e.g., csv and pdf, respectively) from the html report?

What I mean by that is suppose I'm sending this html report to a collaborator and he want to have a separate copy of the tables and figures without having to write any line of code. Does Rmarkdown or knitr enable that in the html report in a form of a button or do I have to programmatically save these to files?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to save them programmatically, automatically, or manually?

Comment: 1) `write.csv()`, 2) `pdf()...dev(off)` in final code chunk with `echo = FALSE`

Comment: I updated my question to clarify these points

Answer (score 5):

If you add `keep_md` option then image files are kept in your directory (like in "xxx_file" folder), which you can send to your colleague.  But I don't think there is an option for tables.

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document:
      keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r libraries}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
```


# Table
```{r print.table,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS,value=1:26)
knitr::kable(df) %>% kable_styling()
```


# Figure
```{r print.params.table,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=id,y=value))+geom_point()
```
````

Answer (score 4):

A table solution I found is the following:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(id = LETTERS, value = 1:26)

df %>% kable(format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  kable_as_image(filename = here("Tables", "test"), 
                 file_format = "jpeg", keep_pdf = F)
```

You can also switch keep_pdf to TRUE, so that you have the tables also in pdf-format.